# Classic ASP - Trying to retrieve total count of specific values

Tags: mysql, asp-classic

I really hope someone can help me here. I am currently coding in classic asp, and I work with an SQL Database.

We have a support page that logs all visits using their network login id into an sql table. And this is where I am having an issue.

I need to display the top 10 highest visitors of the page and the top 10 lowest used visitors. So for instance, if you see below, this is similar to how I want to see the data on the page:

---

### Visitor Visits

- John      50
- Sarah     45
- Tim       40
- Jason     35
- Alex      30
- Rob       25
- Elain     20

---

I cannot for the life of me, figure out how to get this info. All I want is to get a total count of all the visitors visits. Now, we have the data in the database. I just do not know how to place the total count for each visitor on a page and then format the layout from most visits to lowest visits. I have tried everything from searching on the net, and even here. Nothing quite gives me what I need to get this working. I have even tried different methods of using count and total, but, the only successful query is with total visits overall, and I just need it broken down by the visitor column. Can someone please assist me?

UPDATE:

Based on the responses, I am not sure what code to provide. I do not have any code to give. I am simply trying to code in asp-classic a way to query a total count from a specific column for each value. So for instance, if the name "James" visited the site 10 times and the database has him saved 10 times, I would like to query that total on asp. I do not know how to grab the count from the database for each name in the column and get their total visits.

Update 2:

Ok, so this is the code I am trying to fiddle with, based on other resources suggestions on the net:

```
Set Logs = Connect.Execute ("SELECT COUNT(*) AS VISITOR FROM dbo.Tracking GROUP BY VISITOR
```

Comment: post the code you have written so far

Comment: It sounds like this is really an SQL question, not an asp question. Try searching on something like [total per group mysql](https://www.google.com/search?q=total+per+group+mysql). (In MS-SQL, it'd be a simple `SELECT TOP 10 VISITOR, COUNT(*) AS N FROM Tracking GROUP BY VISITOR ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC`. Dunno how the syntax needs to change for MySQL.)

Comment: @martha actually sounds like neither as they don't have any code and expect it to be written for them. Should be closed.

Comment: @lankymart, I already posted why I didn't have any code. And I am not expecting anyone to write it out for me. I was just asking how to go about getting this information. I just needed some guidance. And as I said, I already explained why I didn't have code to post. I looked on the internet for help and wasn't getting anywhere, so  I gave stack overflow a try. And yes the question was about a SELECT statement to create an SQL query within ASP Classic. I thought i made the post  as descriptive the best I can to help anyone trying to help me. Thank you for those who provided me with assistance.

Comment: @Lankymart, I really don't know what to tell you. I was writing a brand new page. I have no code to show. Because I wasn't sure how to even start this. I gave you as much info as I could but I came here hoping for guidance, maybe an example. I spent over 2 days researching this. It almost seems like this was never done before. The language IS IN FACT ASP Classic. The Database IS MySQL. I have the database w/data. But I do not even know where to start with this one. Trust me, I wont be coming back here for help again if this is how people get treated asking for help. Not a good 1st impression.

Comment: It's not about first impressions it's about respecting the people that spend their time trying to help people by looking through [ask] and following the guidelines. You expect help with something that you show no attempt to solve yourself that is off-topic reason number one. I'm sorry but to suggest you spent two days trying to workout how to order some database results in an ASP page and come up with nothing is just either really poor search engine skills or your pulling the wool over our eyes.

Comment: If you have delicate sensibilities and a feeling of entitlement to receive an answer here for no proven effort then [so] is not the community for you. There will always be some who will try and second guess you and sometimes they will get it right, but provide all the information we need to help you in the first place and that will never happen.

Comment: @jrp1982: just ignore Lankymart. He's what's known in volunteer circles as a crispy critter: he's totally burnt out and desperately in need of a break. (Either that, or he needs to be dropped into a project where's he's an utter beginner, where he doesn't even know which way is up, and see how he fares trying to get help from similarly crispy StackOverflow users.) (To clarify: ignore L's *griping*. If he deigns to give you technical advice, you're very lucky and should do your best to follow it.)

Comment: I don't know how much of this you have maanged to do but if it helps you want to research [tag:adodb] and [tag:vbscript] as these will be the two main pieces of tech used in the ASP page. Good luck.

Comment: Hey @Martha you know I have done many times and you know what I did *(because we didn't have the convenience of online resources)* I read a book! I don't mind helping people but I expect them to meet us half way and so does [so] even though you like to flout that on occasion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, MS-SQL not MySQL

I think you have to group the Names and Count them after that.
Select the Top 10 ordered by Count DESC and ASC.

```
SELECT TOP 10 Table1.Visitor, Count(Table1.Visitor) AS Visits
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Table1.Visitor
ORDER BY Count(Table1.Visitor) DESC;
```

**UPDATE 1**

MySQL uses LIMIT instead of TOP ([@w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_first.asp)):

```
SELECT Table1.Visitor, Count(Table1.Visitor) AS Visits
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Table1.Visitor
ORDER BY Count(Table1.Visitor) DESC;
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Why apologise, when simply not posting the answer would suffice? The OP hasn't provided nearly enough information for anyone to form a decent answer, so why do it? Wait for more clarification like everyone else.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is what I needed! Really appreciate your help on this.

Comment: @jrp1982 not according to the updates to the question you left?!?

Comment: @jrp1982 So you're sorted now working page and everything when you didn't have any code to start with? This is just the database query this doesn't magically populate an ASP page and display the results...

Answer (score 1):

As I'm [getting criticised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39872934/classic-asp-trying-to-retrieve-total-count-of-specific-values/39882739#comment67051427_39872934) for not helping...

[@kwnwzlnd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6926295/kwnwzlnd) has [provided you the database query part of the puzzle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39873814/692942) but from what you have said in the question you have no idea how to put that into an ASP page well here is an example.

#### Bit of Background First

Classic ASP out of the box uses the scripting language VBScript which relies heavily on COM components to provide extended functionality like talking to a database. In the VBScript world the library that facilitates this is called ADO *(ActiveX Data Objects)* and is part of MDAC *(Microsoft Data Access Components)*.

[ADODB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms678086(v=vs.85).aspx) provides access to objects that allow you to perform complex operations against a database, these objects include *(among others)*;

- `ADODB.Connection` - Represents an open connection to a data source.
- `ADODB.Recordset` - Represents the entire set of records from a base table or the results of an executed command. At any time, the Recordset object refers to only a single record within the set as the current record.
- `ADODB.Command` - Defines a specific command that you intend to execute against a data source.

#### A Basic Example

```vb
<%
Option Explicit

Dim cmd, sql, conn_str, rs
'Connection String used to connection to the MySQL 
'database - see https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/
conn_str = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User=myUsername;Password=myPassword;Option=3;"
sql = ""
sql = sql & "SELECT Table1.Visitor, Count(Table1.Visitor) AS Visits" & vbCrLf
sql = sql & "FROM Table1" & vbCrLf
sql = sql & "GROUP BY Table1.Visitor" & vbCrLf
sql = sql & "ORDER BY Count(Table1.Visitor) DESC;" & vbCrLf
sql = sql & "LIMIT 10;"

Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
With cmd
  .ActiveConnection = conn_str
  .CommandType = adCmdText 'Named Constant value equals 1
  .CommandText = sql
  'Execute query and return results to a ADODB.Recordset
  Set rs = .Execute()
End With
%>
<ul>
<%
Do While Not rs.EOF
%>
  <li><%= rs("Visitor") & " - " & rs("Visits") %></li>
<%
  'Move to the next record in the returned Recordset.
  Call rs.MoveNext()
Loop
%>
</ul>
<%
'Cleanup after ourselves
Call rs.Close()
Set rs = Nothing
Set cmd = Nothing
%>
```

*<sup>Code is provided untested</sup>*

If I was doing this there are things I would do differently this is just meant as a starting point and moving forward would definitely recommend using `GetRows()` method of the `ADODB.Recordset` to return an 2D `Array` of the recordset that way you can close the database connection and carry on using the data without the database overhead.

#### Bear in Mind

Even with this simple example it will likely raise more questions then it answers.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to say thank you for all of everyones help. A few days after OP was answered, I was able to come up with a way to make your suggestions work for my business needs. I wanted to share an example of what I got working based on your assistance.

I used a specific date format in SQL and had to change the date to an array to make this work. I was even able to add rank! I know it looks amateurish, but it works. And now I understand how it works. Thanks again for all your help.

Below is the example in case anyone is interested (I know its a little late, but figured I would share):

```
Set Logs = Connect.Execute ("SELECT TOP 20 AnalystID, Count(*) AS N FROM dbo.Analysts WHERE Visits = '" & DateArr(0) & DateArr(2) & "' AND AnalystID <> 'siteadmin1' AND AnalystID <> 'siteadmin2' GROUP BY AnalystID ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC")


If Logs.eof Then

 Else
Do While Not Logs.Eof
iRank = iRank + 1


    Set Con = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
    Con.Open = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=" & DatabaseServer & ";Integrated Security=SSPI;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=HRDB;"
            Set myRecordSetRDR = Con.Execute ("SELECT * FROM dbo.HRDBTBLL With(NoLock) WHERE WDW_LGON_ID = '" & Logs("AnalystID") & "'")
            If myRecordSetRDR.EOF Then
            Else
                strANALYSTFULLNAMEReport = myRecordSetRDR("WKR_FLL_NM")
                'response.write myRecordSetRDR("WKR_FLL_NM")
            End If 
    Con.Close () 

    If left(Logs("AnalystID"),3) = "NBE" Then
        strANALYSTFULLNAMEReport = "N/A"
    End If

    If left(Logs("AnalystID"),2) = "ZE" Then
        strANALYSTFULLNAMEReport = "N/A"
    End If      
response.write "<tr>"
    response.write "<td>"
    Response.Write "<center>" & iRank & "</center>"
    Response.write "</td>"
    response.write "<td>" & formatnumber(Logs("N"),0) & "</td><td>" & Logs("AnalystID") & "</td><td>" & strANALYSTFULLNAMEReport & "</td>"
    response.write "</tr>" 
Logs.Movenext
Loop
```